# dyld: Symbol not found: _JVM_CopySwapMemory

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, hotswap

I was setting up my development environment for a java application using java 8u202, HotSwapAgent 1.3.0, DCEVM 8u181 and IntelliJ on a MacOS machine. Everything worked fine for a few days when suddenly this error appeared:

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _JVM_CopySwapMemory
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjava.dylib
  Expected in: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/dcevm/libjvm.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _JVM_CopySwapMemory
  Referenced from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjava.dylib
  Expected in: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/dcevm/libjvm.dylib

I've tried reinstalling JDK, replace JVM by DCEVM not just install DCEVM as an alternative JVV but none of these solutions worked.

Does anyone knows what could cause this or how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JVM_CopySwapMemory` is a new method exposed by the OpenJDK JVM from the January 2019 update.

```
JVM_CopySwapMemory(JNIEnv *env, 
                   jobject srcObj, 
                   jlong srcOffset,
                   jobject dstObj,
                   jlong dstOffset, 
                   jlong size,
                   jlong elemSize)
```

This means you need a specific *patch file* to compile the DCEVM project by yourself, if, indeed, a patch is available.

Unfortunately the latest binary release is compatible only with `8u181`, not with `8u202`.

Comment: What I don't understand is that DCEVM 8u181 was working for java 8u202, I didn't update my JVM so this error shouldn't happen.

Comment: @RafaelMathias probably that method (and the containing library) had never been used. You just were lucky ;) Indeed this has been introduced by `8u20*`.

Comment: Ok, I'll downgrade my JVM so I can continue using HotSwap. Thanks!